# how to add Class in td If duplicate Data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add class same record ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>haris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>ali</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>haris</td>
    </tr>


 </table>
```

how to add class or how to add style in this duplicate record??

Comment: You may want to add a little more detail. Should both records be marked as duplicates or just one (if so, which one). Also, people usually appreciate seeing what you have tried so far. We want to help, but we don't want to write your code for you.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve] and re-read [ask].

Comment: You will have to loop over the table and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over all tr and filter out duplicate tr for applying class.

```
// object for refering text
var obj = {};

// get all tr except the first one which holds header
$('table tr:not(:first-child)').filter(function() {
  // get td contents and trim out space
  var txt = $('td:last-child', this).text().trim();
  // check already defined in object or not
  if (txt in obj)
    // if defined return true, it's dupe
    return true;
  // else define the property
  obj[txt] = true;
  // add class to filtered tr
}).addClass('dup')
```

```js
// object for refering text
var obj = {};

// get all tr except the first one which holds header
$('table tr:not(:first-child)').filter(function() {
  // get td contents and trim out space
  var txt = $('td:last-child', this).text().trim();
  // check already defined in object or not
  if (txt in obj)
  // if defined return true, it's dupe
    return true;
  // else define the property
  obj[txt] = true;
  // add class to filtered tr
}).addClass('dup')
```

```css
.dup {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>haris</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>ali</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>haris</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</table>
```